# What is a Radius Manager and how can I customize it?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, radius

What is a Radius Manager, and how can I customize it ?
The company I work for asked me to build website depending on the radius manager they have,
what I have to do 3 steps webpage to login:
1- check user name and password and get authentication
2- check user balance
3- check if user expires 
4- let the user choose the service he wants from list and save it

It seems simple to me if there is no radius manager ,
but now, I don't know where to start.

any advice , solutions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RADIUS = Remote Authentication Dial-In User Service
It's generally a solution used solely for authentication, authorisation and accounting.
I work for an ISP, and we have a couple (due to migrations and assimilation of other ISPs. I hope I didn't give away whom I work for :P) to authenticate and authorise users to login onto the network. Each company may use it for various duties, but the primary task is still the same. (authentication, authorisation and accounting)

Comment: I also work for ISP and they ask me to customize it as I previously mentioned (4 steps website) ,
any ideas ?

Comment: Your requirements aren't clear in my opinion.
Are they asking you to build a front end for the RADIUS server?
ie. track logins, failed requests, look at RADIUS logs and do stuff.
OR
Are they asking you to build a front end to authenticate against a RADIUS server?
OK, upon having a think, it's probably the latter.

Comment: And RE your comments "It seems simple to me if there is no radius manager". Noo. you want a RADIUS Manager. Your ISP wants to be administer and apply policies to that user base from a central point. RADIUS logs show activity such as wrong passwords, correct logins, static allocations and shaping status. Unless you want to build them a brand new solution which does that, hehe, they want that :P

Comment: I don't know exactly,
but I will make it simple ,
We have a hotspot system the user login depending on the user name and password from a prepaid card .
The new system allows the user to login using his own email and password then refill the card no like telephone prepaid card.

Comment: I think yes they want this

Answer (score 0):

Radius Manager Is Broadband Bandwidth Control System And Handel your User ,billing system for your Isp(Internet Service Provider), you Can Essay Handel Your Isp Company With Radius Manger, like create Plan For Your Service ,add Franchisee Like manager, and Totally Control by You And Its Not Possible Customize it am sour About It Because I Have 2 or 3 Month experience editing radius manager but Nothing Found Because it encoded and Secure Finally I found a Blog There You can get More Detail about It [http://radiusmanagar.blogspot.in](http://radiusmanger.blogspot.in/)